# Google Chrome won't install on Mac

Tags: google-chrome

I'm having a hard time getting Google Chrome to open correctly on my MacBook Pro. I'm using MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6. I'm trying to install Chrome version 69.0.3497.100. I've tried to install using different methods, including homebrew. It appears to install OK, but the app just won't open when I try to click on it in the Applications folder. I'm getting this error when I try to start from the command line:

```
>  Last login: Fri Oct 12 14:15:57 on ttys001 18-0502:~ rgoldman-local$ 
> /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome ; exit;
> crashpad_handler: --database is required Try 'crashpad_handler --help'
> for more information. [1012/145514.178846:ERROR:file_io.cc(89)]
> ReadExactly: expected 8, observed 0
> [1012/145514.179295:ERROR:crash_report_database_mac.mm(95)] mkdir : No
> such file or directory (2) logout Saving session... ...copying shared
> history... ...saving history...truncating history files...
> ...completed.
> 
> [Process completed]
```

Comment: You're running a desktop environment right? You should be able to install chrome through GUI and not need to do it on the terminal. Have you followed the process below: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7550274?hl=en ?

Comment: Hi, yes, I've tried installing using the normal means of the GUI installer. I only included the terminal command above  because it prints out the actual error during startup. Which is that there is no such file called "crash_report_database_mac.mm"

Comment: And there is no information when you run "crashpad_handler --help"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual binary to launch Google Chrome is "/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/GoogleChromeOrWhateverTheBinaryIsCalled"
And if that fails (The suggestion I'm about to make is not recommended by the tech communtiy), try adding "sudo" before the binary (space after sudo) and try launching it one more time

Comment: Yes, this actually worked!

```$ sudo ./Google\ Chrome```

Comment: Now, how did this happen? Can I just change the perms on the binary?

Comment: I don't quite understand, because I am an admin on my own laptop, and the perms for the binary are 755. I tried 777 but that doesn't help. What is sudo doing that changing permissions doesn't do?

Comment: Never mind, I think the user had some issues with permissions. I created a new user and don't have the issue anymore.

Comment: Glad my answer helped, and that you found the root cause!
I just found by quickly googling that you can repair permissions for a user by using Disk Utility and running first aid on the disk, which might help with the existing user you had trouble with.

Comment: You cannot find downloaded files if you run it with sudo

Answer (score 4):

This is most likely an access issue, where Chrome does not have access to the necessary locations to add directories and content. Try these steps:

Open a terminal window.

In the terminal window, there will be a username in the command prompt of the window. Mine looks like this:

```
    Last login: Tue Aug 27 09:51:28 on ttys000
    jacobs-mbp:~ jyackeno$
```

you want the text between the '~' and the '$'. That's your username for the mac.
    As an example:
    My username (from above) is `jyackeno`.

now, type this into the Terminal window:

`sudo chmod 777 /Users/username-from-terminal/Library/Application\ Support/Google/chrome`

AND change:
    `username-from-terminal`
    with the text between the '~' and the '$' from the earlier step.

As an example:
    The command I enter is:

```
sudo chmod 777 /Users/jyackeno/Library/Application\ Support/Google/chrome
```

You will be prompted to enter a password. Enter your mac login password.

Now try starting Chrome. It should start successfully.

Comment: Thanks, I resolved the issue by creating a new user. (See comments in the other answer.) For a little background, it was a MacBook that my company issued to me after IT ran some scripts to prep it. i think their scripts screwed up the permissions for the user they created for me.

Comment: Thank you. The `chrome` folder didn't exist for me so I ran the command on the parent directory instead and it did the trick.